# Reading HTML attributes with Casper/Phantom differ on environment

Tags: javascript, css, heroku, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a script to parse sites. When parsing this site: http://www.pencils.com/all-pencils/carpenter-pencils/forestchoice-carpenter-pencils-12-count - I found that the values that I get from the element with id="logo", differ depending on whether I launch the script from my production server (Heroku) or my local machine.

In order to investigate further, I decided to take a screenshot of the page from Heroku and from my local machine.  Here are the results:

Heroku: [Screenshot from Heroku](http://postimg.org/image/lbvpesnpx/full/) 
Local machine: [Screenshot from local machine](http://postimg.org/image/euwyw1q2z/full/)

As you can see the fonts are different. Why, and how can I solve this?

Any ideas why can this be happening?

Comment: Can you please provide your own answer as descibed in your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889090/reading-html-attributes-with-casper-phantom-differ-on-environment#comment31386348_20908302)?

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I can think,

you aren't waiting long enough for the logo to be loaded.

for some reason your casper script in heroku is set to not download images.

maybe try setting the viewport to a larger size?

Comment: Hi Chris. Actually it was the fact that Heroku was using another font which was wider, and was pushing the logo down. Once I installed the missing font on Heroku it worked great.